# show div as popoup when clicking on image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an image.

I want to show different divs as popup when user clicks on particular area of the image.

I want to do it using jquery & html.

Can any one help me with this.

Comment: what you have triedd?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

#### Use SimpleModal

You can use the plugin [**SimpleModal**](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/) to achieve what you wanna do.

> [**SimpleModal**](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/) is a lightweight jQuery Plugin which provides a powerful interface for modal dialog development. Think of it as a modal dialog framework. SimpleModal gives you the flexibility to build whatever you can envision, while shielding you from related cross-browser issues inherent with UI development.

Using that, you can either call an already existing `div` or create a modal on the fly.

#### Calling an existing `div`:

```
$("#element-id").modal();
```

#### Making a modal on the fly:

```
$.modal("<div><h1>SimpleModal</h1></div>");
```

#### Giving options:

```
$("#element-id").modal({options});
$.modal("<div><h1>SimpleModal</h1></div>", {options});
```

#### Demos:

[image: Screenshot]

#### More demos here: http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal-demos/

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example of sample solution: http://jsfiddle.net/htEvT/2/

**JavaScript**

```
$('#rabbit').click(function (e) {
    var offset = $(this).offset(),
        left = e.pageX - offset.left,
        top = e.pageY - offset.top;
    if (top > $(this).height() / 2) {
        alertDiv('You\'ve cliked under the middle.', 'alert-white');
    } else {
        alertDiv('You\'ve cliked above the middle.', 'alert-gray');
    }
});

function alertDiv(text, cssClass) {
    var alrt = $('<div class="alert ' + cssClass + '">' + text + '</div>');
    $(document.body).append(alrt);
    alrt.click(function () {
        alrt.remove();
    });
}
​
```

**CSS**

```
.alert {
    position: absolute;
    left: 30px;
    top: 30px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.alert-white {
    background: white;
}
.alert-gray {
    background: #ccc;
}
​
```

**HTML**

```
<img src="http://www.clermontanimal.net/images/lop_rabbit_easter.jpg" id="rabbit" alt="" />​
```

If there are any issues with my solution please let me know. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use Image Map on image and attach fancy box on different sections of image. Since, you have not posted code so I can't provide coding solution for the same.

Answer (score 0):

Something like below should give you an Idea how to do this:

```
$("img").click(function() {
  $("body").append("<div class='newdiv'></div>")
})



.newdiv{width:100px; height:300px;border:1px solid red;}
```

Answer (score 0):

My favorite is **[Fancybox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/).**

I'm yet to see something it cannot do. Great documentation and widely used so if you need help there is a high chance somebody else has asked the same question, and can be resolved with a simple google.

Answer (score 0):

Create a DIV named "imgbox" on the HTML page on which your thumbnail images will be shown. The DIV and the CSS element ID associated with the DIV is shown below

```
<div id="imgbox"></div>
```

the css

```
#imgbox 
{
vertical-align : middle;
position : absolute;
border: 1px solid #999;
background : #FFFFFF; 
filter: Alpha(Opacity=100);
visibility : hidden;
height : 200px;
width : 200px;
z-index : 50;
overflow : hidden;
text-align : center;
```

}

Here is the JavaScript code to show the popup image:
Get the left and top positions of the thumbnail image:

```
function getElementLeft(elm) 
{
 var x = 0;

//set x to elm’s offsetLeft
x = elm.offsetLeft;

//set elm to its offsetParent
elm = elm.offsetParent;

//use while loop to check if elm is null
// if not then add current elm’s offsetLeft to x
//offsetTop to y and set elm to its offsetParent

while(elm != null)
{
    x = parseInt(x) + parseInt(elm.offsetLeft);
    elm = elm.offsetParent;
}
return x;
}

function getElementTop(elm) 
{
 var y = 0;

//set x to elm’s offsetLeft
y = elm.offsetTop;

//set elm to its offsetParent
elm = elm.offsetParent;

//use while loop to check if elm is null
// if not then add current elm’s offsetLeft to x
//offsetTop to y and set elm to its offsetParent

while(elm != null)
{
    y = parseInt(y) + parseInt(elm.offsetTop);
    elm = elm.offsetParent;
}

return y;
}
```

Get the thumbnail image source, make the DIV visible, increase the height and width to the required size, and attach the image to the DIV.

```
function Large(obj)
```

{
    var imgbox=document.getElementById("imgbox");
    imgbox.style.visibility='visible';
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src=obj.src;
    img.style.width='200px';
    img.style.height='200px';

```
if(img.addEventListener){
    img.addEventListener('mouseout',Out,false);
} else {
    img.attachEvent('onmouseout',Out);
}             
imgbox.innerHTML='';
imgbox.appendChild(img);
imgbox.style.left=(getElementLeft(obj)-50) +'px';
imgbox.style.top=(getElementTop(obj)-50) + 'px';
}
Hide the DIV at mouse out.

function Out()
{
 document.getElementById("imgbox").style.visibility='hidden';
}
```

Add a OnMouseOver client-side event call for the thumbnail images to show the popup image on mouse-over.

```
<img id='img1' src='images/Sample.jpg' onmouseover="Large(this)" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If the area is square, you can place a transparent element *over* the desired area, and give it a simple `onClick` event.